# Elo Rating Tracking Applet - Release into GNU?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a little applet that I wrote in Python and Tkinter, and I was wondering what a good way would be to make it public, or open source or whatever.

I think it's quite fun.  You can add players, add singles games, add doubles games, and then it gives you a table of recent games and ratings with a bunch of stats (games played, scores, streaks etc).

You need to run the Python code, rather than just run an executable.

What would be a good way to go about releasing this into the wild?  It would probably be a handy example of Tkinter code (which would be nice), and might even be useful for someone trying to implement an elo system somewhere.  And I'm sure that some interesting improvements could be made.

I've stripped out some of the doubles features to make it fit in the limit (although I'm sure a good coder could do it with cleverer class structures).

The full code is [here](http://dumptext.com/lfvF2a20), which includes a little code to add random games (you need to add players first).

```
import datetime
import pickle
from operator import attrgetter #https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html
import re
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as tkFont   #
import itertools
import bisect
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
# implement the default mpl key bindings
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler

from matplotlib.figure import Figure

#To do list
# - make it an executable for both ubuntu and windows

class AutocompleteCombobox(ttk.Combobox):  #https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2012-January/003041.html

    def set_completion_list(self, completion_list, menu):
        """Use our completion list as our drop down selection menu, arrows move through menu."""
        self._completion_list = completion_list  #sorted(completion_list, key=str.lower) # Work with a sorted list
        self._hits = []
        self._hit_index = 0
        self.position = 0
        self.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.handle_keyrelease)
        self['values'] = self._completion_list  # Setup our popup menu
        self.menu = menu

    def autocomplete(self, delta=0):
        """autocomplete the Combobox, delta may be 0/1/-1 to cycle through possible hits"""
        if delta: # need to delete selection otherwise we would fix the current position
            self.delete(self.position, END)
        else: # set position to end so selection starts where textentry ended
            self.position = len(self.get())
        # collect hits
        _hits = []
        for element in self._completion_list:
            if element.lower().startswith(self.get().lower()): # Match case insensitively
                _hits.append(element)
        # if we have a new hit list, keep this in mind
        if _hits != self._hits:
            self._hit_index = 0
            self._hits=_hits
        # only allow cycling if we are in a known hit list
        if _hits == self._hits and self._hits:
            self._hit_index = (self._hit_index + delta) % len(self._hits)
        # now finally perform the auto completion
        if self._hits:
            self.delete(0,END)
            self.insert(0,self._hits[self._hit_index])
            self.select_range(self.position,END)

    def handle_keyrelease(self, event):
        """event handler for the keyrelease event on this widget"""
        if event.keysym == "BackSpace":
            self.delete(self.index(INSERT), END)
            self.position = self.index(END)
        if event.keysym == "Left":
            if self.position < self.index(END): # delete the selection
                self.delete(self.position, END)
            else:
                self.position = self.position-1 # delete one character
                self.delete(self.position, END)
        if event.keysym == "Right":
            self.position = self.index(END) # go to end (no selection)
        if len(event.keysym) == 1:
            self.autocomplete()
            self.menu.selected()
        # No need for up/down, we'll jump to the popup
        # list at the position of the autocompletion


class Player:
  def __init__(self,name,singles=1,rating=1200):
    self.name = name
    self.singles=singles  #1=singles,0=doubles,2=pairs
    self.initial_rating = rating
    self.rating = rating
    self.active = False
    self.games_played = 0
    self.wins = 0
    self.losses = 0
    self.draws = 0
    self.points_for = 0
    self.points_against = 0
    self.streak = 0  #positive is winning/negative is losing
    self.max_winning_streak = 0
    self.max_losing_streak = 0
    self.max_rating = rating
    self.min_rating = rating
    self.last_game = datetime.datetime.now()

  def __str__(self):
    return "%s,%d,%s"%(self.name,self.rating,self.singles)

  def __repr__(self):
    return "Player('%s',%d,%s)"%(self.name,self.rating,self.singles)

  def reset(self):
    self.rating = self.initial_rating
    self.active = False
    self.games_played = 0
    self.wins = 0
    self.losses = 0
    self.draws = 0
    self.points_for = 0
    self.points_against = 0
    self.streak = 0  #positive is winning/negative is losing
    self.max_winning_streak = 0
    self.max_losing_streak = 0
    self.max_rating = self.initial_rating
    self.min_rating = self.initial_rating

class Game:
  def __init__(self,player1,player2,score1,score2,date):
    self.player1 = player1
    self.player2 = player2
    self.score1 = score1
    self.score2 = score2
    self.date = date
    self.play()
  def __repr__(self):
    return "Game(%s,%s,%d,%d,%s)"%(self.player1,self.player2,self.score1,self.score2,self.date)
  def __str__(self):
    return "%s:\t%s:%d\t%s:%d)"%(self.date,self.player1,self.score1,self.player2,self.score2)
  def play(self):
    #datetime
    self.player1.last_game = self.date
    self.player2.last_game = self.date
    #points
    self.player1.points_for+=self.score1
    self.player1.points_against+=self.score2
    self.player2.points_for += self.score2
    self.player2.points_against+=self.score1
    #games
    self.player1.games_played+=1
    self.player2.games_played+=1
    #wins & streaks
    if self.score1>self.score2:
      self.player1.wins+=1
      self.player2.losses+=1
      self.player1.streak = max([1,self.player1.streak+1])
      self.player2.streak = min([-1,self.player2.streak-1])
      self.player1.max_winning_streak = max([self.player1.max_winning_streak, self.player1.streak])
      self.player2.max_losing_streak  = max([self.player2.max_losing_streak, -self.player2.streak])
    elif self.score1==self.score2:
      self.player1.draws+=1
      self.player2.draws+=1
      self.player1.streak=0
      self.player2.streak=0
    else:
      self.player1.losses+=1
      self.player2.wins+=1
      self.player2.streak = max([1,self.player2.streak+1])
      self.player1.streak = min([-1,self.player1.streak-1])
      self.player2.max_winning_streak = max([self.player2.max_winning_streak, self.player2.streak])
      self.player1.max_losing_streak  = max([self.player1.max_losing_streak, -self.player1.streak])
    #rating
    expected_score = 1.0/(1+10**((self.player2.rating-self.player1.rating)/400.0))
    max_score = max([self.score1,self.score2])
    actual_score = (max_score+self.score1-self.score2)/(2.0*max_score)
    rating_change = int(round(32*(actual_score-expected_score),0))
    self.player1.rating += rating_change
    self.player2.rating -= rating_change
    self.rating_change = rating_change
    #max/min rating
    self.player1.max_rating = max([self.player1.max_rating,self.player1.rating])
    self.player1.min_rating = min([self.player1.min_rating,self.player1.rating])
    self.player2.max_rating = max([self.player2.max_rating,self.player2.rating])
    self.player2.min_rating = min([self.player2.min_rating,self.player2.rating])

class DoublesGame:
  def __init__(self,t1p1,t1p2,t2p1,t2p2,score1,score2,date):
    self.t1p1 = t1p1
    self.t1p2 = t1p2
    self.t2p1 = t2p1
    self.t2p2 = t2p2
    self.score1 = score1
    self.score2 = score2
    self.date = date

    self.play()
  def __repr__(self):
    return "DoublesGame(%s,%s,%s,%s,%d,%d,%s)"%(self.t1p1,self.t1p2,self.t2p1,self.t2p2,self.score1,self.score2,self.date)
  def __str__(self):
    return "%s:\t%s/%s:%d\t%s/%s:%d)"%(self.date,self.t1p1,self.t1p2,self.score1,self.t2p1,self.t2p2,self.score2)
  def play(self):
    #Find/make pairs (stripped out for codereview)
    pass

def saveGames(fileName="foos.pkl"):
  myF = open(fileName,"wb")
  pickle.dump((players,games,doubles_games,settings),myF)
  myF.close()

def loadGames(fileName="foos.pkl"):
  global players
  global games
  global doubles_games
  global settings
  myF = open(fileName,'rb')
  a = pickle.load(myF)
  myF.close()
  players,games,doubles_games,b = a
  settings.update(b)  

def makeGraph(singles=1):
  if singles==2: singles=0
  d = dict()
  keys = ["Date"]
  for p in players:
    if p.singles==singles:
      keys.append(p.name)
      d[p.name]=[1200]
  if singles==1:
    d["Date"]=[games[0].date - datetime.timedelta(days=1)]

    for g in games:
      d["Date"].append(g.date)
      for p in players:
        if p.singles==singles:
          d[p.name].append(d[p.name][-1])
      d[g.player1.name][-1] = d[g.player1.name][-1] + g.rating_change
      d[g.player2.name][-1] = d[g.player2.name][-1] - g.rating_change
  else:
    d["Date"]=[doubles_games[0].date - datetime.timedelta(days=1)]

    for g in doubles_games:
      d["Date"].append(g.date)
      for p in players:
        if p.singles==singles:
          d[p.name].append(d[p.name][-1])
      d[g.t1p1.name][-1] = d[g.t1p1.name][-1] + g.rating_change
      d[g.t1p2.name][-1] = d[g.t1p2.name][-1] + g.rating_change
      d[g.t2p1.name][-1] = d[g.t2p1.name][-1] - g.rating_change
      d[g.t2p2.name][-1] = d[g.t2p2.name][-1] - g.rating_change

  ls = ["--","-",":"]
  cs = ["g","b","r","k"]

  annot2=[]
  for k in keys[1:]:
    annot2.append(d[k][-1]-2)

  annot=[]
  sortedKeys=[]
  for a,k in zip(annot2,keys[1:]):
    i=bisect.bisect(annot,a)
    annot.insert(i,a)
    sortedKeys.insert(i,k)
  annot.reverse()
  sortedKeys.reverse()
  #print(annot,sortedKeys)


  cont=True
  #print("Optimizing annotations...",)
  while cont:
    for i in range(len(annot)-1):
      if annot[i] - annot[i+1]<=5:
        annot[i] = annot[i]+0.5
        annot[i+1] = annot[i+1]-0.5
        cont = False
    cont = not cont
  #print("done!")

  l=len(d[k])

  f = Figure(figsize=(12,8))
  pt = f.add_subplot(111)

  for i,k in enumerate(sortedKeys):
    if k=="Date": continue
    pt.plot(range(l),d[k],cs[sortedKeys.index(k)%len(cs)]+ls[sortedKeys.index(k)%len(ls)],label = k)
    pt.annotate(k,((l-1)*1.01,annot[i]),color=cs[sortedKeys.index(k)%len(cs)])
  pt.set_ylabel("Rating")
  pt.set_xlabel("Games")
  pt.set_xlim((-l*0.2,l*1.12))
  pt.set_title("Ratings at "+datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
  pt.legend(loc="upper left")

  xr,xl=[0],[d["Date"][0].strftime("%d-%b")]
  for i,dt in enumerate(d["Date"]):
    if dt != xl[-1]:
      if i-xr[-1]>l*0.05:
        xr.append(i)
        xl.append(dt.strftime("%d-%b"))
  if xr[-1]<0.95*l:
    xr.append(l)
    xl.append(dt.strftime("%d-%b"))
  else:
    xr[-1]=l
    xl[-1]=d["Date"][-1].strftime("%d-%b")

  pt.set_xticks(xr)
  pt.set_xticklabels(xl,rotation=90)

  return f


class AddPlayer:
  def __init__(self,mainmenu):
    self.root = Toplevel(mainmenu.root)
    self.root.title("Add new player")
    mainframe = ttk.Frame(self.root,padding="3 3 12 12")
    mainframe.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
    mainframe.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    mainframe.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

    self.name = StringVar()
    self.warning = StringVar()

    self.name_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=12, textvariable=self.name)
    self.name_entry.grid(column=2,row=1,sticky=(W,E))

    ttk.Label(mainframe,textvariable=self.warning).grid(column=1,row=2,columnspan=2,sticky=(W,E))
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="Add Player", command=self.addPlayer).grid(column=3,row=1,sticky=W)
    self.root.bind('<Return>',self.addPlayer)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="Close",command=self.quit).grid(column=3,row=2,sticky=W)
    self.root.bind('<Escape>',self.quit)

    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Player's name:").grid(column=1,row=1,sticky=W)

    for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5,pady=5)
    self.root.focus()
    self.name_entry.focus()

    self.root.mainloop()

  def quit(self,*args):
    self.root.destroy()

  def addPlayer(self,*args):
    newname = self.name.get()
    newname = newname.strip()
    newname = re.sub(r'[ ]',"_",newname)
    newname = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9_]', '', newname)
    if newname == "":
      self.warning.set("Name must be alphanumeric!")
      return
    for p in players:
      if p.name.lower()==newname.lower():
        self.warning.set("Name %s already used!"%newname)
        self.name.set("")
        self.name_entry.focus()
        return
    newname = newname[0].upper()+newname[1:].lower()
    players.append(Player(newname,True))
    players.append(Player(newname,False))
    saveGames()
    self.warning.set("Player %s added!"%newname)
    self.name.set("")
    self.name_entry.focus()

class AddGame:
  def __init__(self,mainmenu):
    self.mainmenu = mainmenu
    self.root = Toplevel(mainmenu.root)
    self.root.title("Add singles game")
    mainframe = ttk.Frame(self.root,padding="3 3 12 12")
    mainframe.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
    mainframe.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    mainframe.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

    self.score1 = StringVar()
    self.score2 = StringVar()
    self.warning = StringVar()

    self.score1.set('0')
    self.score2.set('0')

    self.ps=[]
    for p in players:
      if p.singles==True:
        self.ps.append(p.name)
    self.ps.sort()
    self.ps1 = self.ps[:]
    self.ps2 = self.ps[:]

    self.player1_combo = AutocompleteCombobox(mainframe, width=12, font=tkFont.Font(size=28))
    self.player1_combo.grid(column=2,row=2,sticky=(W,E))
    self.player1_combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.selected)
    self.player2_combo = AutocompleteCombobox(mainframe, width=12, font=tkFont.Font(size=28))
    self.player2_combo.grid(column=2,row=4,sticky=(W,E))
    self.player2_combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.selected)
    self.selected()

    self.score1_spin = Spinbox(mainframe, width=5, from_=0, to=settings['maxScore'], textvariable = self.score1, font=tkFont.Font(size=28))
    self.score1_spin.grid(column=3,row=2,sticky=(W))
    self.score2_spin = Spinbox(mainframe, width=5, from_=0, to=settings['maxScore'], textvariable = self.score2, font=tkFont.Font(size=28))
    self.score2_spin.grid(column=3,row=4,sticky=(W))


    ttk.Label(mainframe,textvariable=self.warning).grid(column=1,row=5,columnspan=4,sticky=(W,E))
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="Add Game", command=self.addGame).grid(column=4,row=2,sticky=W)
    self.root.bind('<Return>',self.addGame)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="Close",command=self.quit).grid(column=4,row=3,sticky=W)
    self.root.bind('<Escape>',self.quit)

    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Player 1").grid(column=1,row=2,sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="versus").grid(column=2,row=3,sticky=E)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Player 2").grid(column=1,row=4,sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Players:").grid(column=2,row=1,sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Score:").grid(column=3,row=1,sticky=W)

    for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5,pady=5)
    self.root.focus()
    self.player1_combo.focus()

    self.root.mainloop()

  def selected(self,*args):
    self.ps1 = self.ps[:]
    self.ps2 = self.ps[:]
    self.player1 = self.player1_combo.get()
    self.player2 = self.player2_combo.get()
    cboVals = [self.player1,self.player2]
    i=0
    for cboList in [self.ps1,self.ps2]:
      cboVals2 = cboVals[:]
      cboVals2.pop(i)
      i+=1
      for cboVal in cboVals2:
        try:
          cboList.remove(cboVal)
        except:
          pass
    self.player1_combo.set_completion_list(self.ps1,self)
    self.player2_combo.set_completion_list(self.ps2,self)

  def quit(self,*args):
    self.root.destroy()

  def addGame(self,*args):
    p1=0
    p2=0
    for p in players:
      if p.name == self.player1_combo.get() and p.singles==True:
        p1 = p
      if p.name == self.player2_combo.get() and p.singles==True:
        p2 = p
    if p1==0:
      self.warning.set("Select player 1!")
      self.player1_combo.focus()
      return
    if p2==0:
      self.warning.set("Select player 2!")
      self.player2_combo.focus()
      return
    if p1==p2:
      self.warning.set("Must have different players!")
      return
    if int(self.score1.get())<settings['minMaxScore'] and int(self.score2.get())<settings['minMaxScore']:
      self.warning.set("One of the players must score at least %d!"%settings['minMaxScore'])
      self.score1_spin.focus()
      return
    if (not settings['allowDraw']) and int(self.score1.get())==int(self.score2.get()):
      self.warning.set("Draws are not allowed (change in settings)")
      return
    games.append(Game(p1,p2,int(self.score1.get()),int(self.score2.get()),datetime.datetime.now()))
    saveGames()
    self.warning.set("Game added!")
    self.score1.set("0")
    self.score2.set("0")
    self.mainmenu.update()

class AddDoublesGame:
  def __init__(self,mainmenu):
    #stripped out for code review
    pass

class EditGame:
  def __init__(self,mainmenu,game):
    self.mainmenu = mainmenu
    self.game = game
    self.root = Toplevel(mainmenu.root)
    self.root.title("Edit singles game")
    mainframe = ttk.Frame(self.root,padding="3 3 12 12")
    mainframe.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
    mainframe.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    mainframe.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

    self.score1 = StringVar()
    self.score2 = StringVar()
    self.warning = StringVar()


    self.score1.set(game.score1)
    self.score2.set(game.score2)

    self.ps=[]
    for p in players:
      if p.singles==True:
        self.ps.append(p.name)
    self.ps.sort()
    self.ps1 = self.ps[:]
    self.ps2 = self.ps[:]

    self.player1_combo = AutocompleteCombobox(mainframe, width=12, font=tkFont.Font(size=28))
    self.player1_combo.grid(column=2,row=2,sticky=(W,E))
    self.player1_combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.selected)
    self.player2_combo = AutocompleteCombobox(mainframe, width=12, font=tkFont.Font(size=28))
    self.player2_combo.grid(column=2,row=4,sticky=(W,E))
    self.player2_combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.selected)
    self.selected()

    self.player1_combo.set(game.player1.name)
    self.player2_combo.set(game.player2.name)

    self.score1_spin = Spinbox(mainframe, width=5, from_=0, to=settings['maxScore'], textvariable = self.score1, font=tkFont.Font(size=28))
    self.score1_spin.grid(column=3,row=2,sticky=(W))
    self.score2_spin = Spinbox(mainframe, width=5, from_=0, to=settings['maxScore'], textvariable = self.score2, font=tkFont.Font(size=28))
    self.score2_spin.grid(column=3,row=4,sticky=(W))

    ttk.Label(mainframe,textvariable=self.warning).grid(column=1,row=5,columnspan=4,sticky=(W,E))
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="Edit Game", command=self.addGame).grid(column=4,row=2,sticky=W)
    self.root.bind('<Return>',self.addGame)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="Cancel",command=self.quit).grid(column=4,row=3,sticky=W)
    self.root.bind('<Escape>',self.quit)

    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Player 1").grid(column=1,row=2,sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="versus").grid(column=2,row=3,sticky=E)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Player 2").grid(column=1,row=4,sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Players:").grid(column=2,row=1,sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Score:").grid(column=3,row=1,sticky=W)

    for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5,pady=5)
    self.root.focus()
    self.player1_combo.focus()

    self.root.mainloop()

  def selected(self,*args):
    self.ps1 = self.ps[:]
    self.ps2 = self.ps[:]
    self.player1 = self.player1_combo.get()
    self.player2 = self.player2_combo.get()
    cboVals = [self.player1,self.player2]
    i=0
    for cboList in [self.ps1,self.ps2]:
      cboVals2 = cboVals[:]
      cboVals2.pop(i)
      i+=1
      for cboVal in cboVals2:
        try:
          cboList.remove(cboVal)
        except:
          pass
    self.player1_combo.set_completion_list(self.ps1,self)
    self.player2_combo.set_completion_list(self.ps2,self)   

  def quit(self,*args):
    self.root.destroy()

  def addGame(self,*args):
    p1=0
    p2=0
    for p in players:
      if p.name == self.player1_combo.get() and p.singles==True:
        p1 = p
      if p.name == self.player2_combo.get() and p.singles==True:
        p2 = p
    if p1==0:
      self.warning.set("Select player 1!")
      self.player1_combo.focus()
      return
    if p2==0:
      self.warning.set("Select player 2!")
      self.player2_combo.focus()
      return
    if p1==p2:
      self.warning.set("Must have different players!")
      return
    if int(self.score1.get())<settings['minMaxScore'] and int(self.score2.get())<settings['minMaxScore']:
      self.warning.set("One of the players must score at least %d!"%settings['minMaxScore'])
      self.score1_spin.focus()
      return
    if (not settings['allowDraw']) and int(self.score1.get())==int(self.score2.get()):
      self.warning.set("Draws are not allowed (change in settings)")
      return
    self.game.player1 = p1
    self.game.player2 = p2
    self.game.score1 = int(self.score1.get())
    self.game.score2 = int(self.score2.get())
    recalculate(True)
    saveGames()
    self.mainmenu.update()
    self.root.destroy()

class EditDoublesGame:
  def __init__(self,mainmenu,game):
    #stripped out for code review
    pass

class PlayerStats:
  def __init__(self,mainmenu):
    self.root = Toplevel(mainmenu.root)
    self.root.title("Player Stats")
    self.root.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    self.root.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
    self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(self.root,padding="3 3 12 12")
    self.mainframe.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
    self.mainframe.columnconfigure(3,weight=1)
    self.mainframe.rowconfigure(2,weight=1)

    self.gameType = StringVar()

    self.gameType.set(1)
    self.tree_headers=["Opponent","Rating taken","Games","Wins","Losses","Goals by","Goals on",
                 "Av goals by","Av goals on","Streak","Max win streak","Max lose streak",
               "5-0","5-1","5-2","5-3","5-4","4-5","3-5","2-5","1-5","0-5"]

    self.gameType_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self.mainframe,text="Game type")  #,padding="3 3 12 12")
    self.gameType_frame.grid(column=2,row=1,sticky=(W,N))
    self.gameType_frame['borderwidth']=2
    self.gameType_frame['relief']='solid'
    self.display_frame = ttk.Frame(self.mainframe,padding="3 3 12 12")
    self.display_frame.grid(column=1,row=2, columnspan = 3,sticky=(W,N,E,S))
    self.display_frame['borderwidth']=2
    self.display_frame['relief']='sunken'
    self.display_frame.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    self.display_frame.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

    self.player_combo = AutocompleteCombobox(self.mainframe, width=12, font=tkFont.Font(size=28))
    self.player_combo.grid(column=1,row=1,sticky=(W,E))
    self.player_combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.selected)

    self.singles_radio = ttk.Radiobutton(self.gameType_frame,text="Singles",variable=self.gameType,value=1,command=self.selected)
    self.singles_radio.grid(column=1,row=1,sticky=(W,N))
    self.doubles_radio = ttk.Radiobutton(self.gameType_frame,text="Doubles",variable=self.gameType,value=0,command=self.selected)
    self.doubles_radio.grid(column=2,row=1,sticky=(W,N))
    self.pairs_radio = ttk.Radiobutton(self.gameType_frame,text="Pairs",variable=self.gameType,value=2,command=self.selected)
    self.pairs_radio.grid(column=3,row=1,sticky=(W,N))


    for child in self.mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=10,pady=10)

    self.selected()
    self.player_combo.focus()
    self.root.mainloop()

  def selected(self,*args):
    player = 0
    self.ps=[]
    for p in players:
      if p.singles==int(self.gameType.get()):
        self.ps.append(p.name)
        if p.name == self.player_combo.get():
          player = p
    if self.player_combo.get() not in self.ps:
      self.player_combo.set("")
    self.ps.sort()
    self.player_combo.set_completion_list(self.ps,self)
    #update treeview
    if player != 0:
      self.tree_list = dict()
      if int(self.gameType.get())==1:    #######  Singles
        for g in games:
          if g.player1==player:
            opponent = g.player2
            p1=1
          elif g.player2==player:
            opponent = g.player1
            p1=-1
          else:
            continue
          if opponent.name not in self.tree_list.keys():
            self.tree_list[opponent.name] = [opponent.name,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
          self.tree_list[opponent.name][1] += p1*g.rating_change  #rating taken
          self.tree_list[opponent.name][2] += 1           #games
          if p1*g.score1 > p1*g.score2:   #player wins
            self.tree_list[opponent.name][3] += 1  #wins
            self.tree_list[opponent.name][9] = max([1,self.tree_list[opponent.name][9]+1])  #streak
            self.tree_list[opponent.name][10] = max([self.tree_list[opponent.name][10],self.tree_list[opponent.name][9]]) #max win streak
          elif p1*g.score2 > p1*g.score1:   #player loses
            self.tree_list[opponent.name][4] += 1  #losses
            self.tree_list[opponent.name][9] = min([-1,self.tree_list[opponent.name][9]-1])  #streak
            self.tree_list[opponent.name][11] = max([self.tree_list[opponent.name][10],-self.tree_list[opponent.name][9]]) #max lose streak
          else:               #draw
            self.tree_list[opponent.name][9] =0  #streak
          if p1==1:
            self.tree_list[opponent.name][5] += g.score1  #goals by
            self.tree_list[opponent.name][6] += g.score2  #goals on
            if g.score1==5:
              self.tree_list[opponent.name][12+g.score2] += 1     #game count
            else:
              self.tree_list[opponent.name][21-g.score1] +=1      #game count
          else:
            self.tree_list[opponent.name][5] += g.score2  #goals by
            self.tree_list[opponent.name][6] += g.score1  #goals on
            if g.score2==5:
              self.tree_list[opponent.name][12+g.score1] += 1     #game count
            else:
              self.tree_list[opponent.name][21-g.score2] +=1      #game count
        for k in self.tree_list.keys():
          self.tree_list[k][7] = "%.3f"%(1.0*self.tree_list[k][5]/self.tree_list[k][2])
          self.tree_list[k][8] = "%.3f"%(1.0*self.tree_list[k][6]/self.tree_list[k][2])
          self.tree_list[k] = [str(i) for i in self.tree_list[k]]
      elif int(self.gameType.get())==2:    #######  Pairs
        for g in doubles_games:
          if g.team1==player:
            opponent = g.team2
            p1=1
          elif g.team2==player:
            opponent = g.team1
            p1=-1
          else:
            continue
          if opponent.name not in self.tree_list.keys():
            self.tree_list[opponent.name] = [opponent.name,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
          self.tree_list[opponent.name][1] += p1*g.rating_change2  #rating taken
          self.tree_list[opponent.name][2] += 1           #games
          if p1*g.score1 > p1*g.score2:   #player wins
            self.tree_list[opponent.name][3] += 1  #wins
            self.tree_list[opponent.name][9] = max([1,self.tree_list[opponent.name][9]+1])  #streak
            self.tree_list[opponent.name][10] = max([self.tree_list[opponent.name][10],self.tree_list[opponent.name][9]]) #max win streak
          elif p1*g.score2 > p1*g.score1:   #player loses
            self.tree_list[opponent.name][4] += 1  #losses
            self.tree_list[opponent.name][9] = min([-1,self.tree_list[opponent.name][9]-1])  #streak
            self.tree_list[opponent.name][11] = max([self.tree_list[opponent.name][10],-self.tree_list[opponent.name][9]]) #max lose streak
          else:               #draw
            self.tree_list[opponent.name][9] =0  #streak
          if p1==1:
            self.tree_list[opponent.name][5] += g.score1  #goals by
            self.tree_list[opponent.name][6] += g.score2  #goals on
            if g.score1==5:
              self.tree_list[opponent.name][12+g.score2] += 1     #game count
            else:
              self.tree_list[opponent.name][21-g.score1] +=1      #game count
          else:
            self.tree_list[opponent.name][5] += g.score2  #goals by
            self.tree_list[opponent.name][6] += g.score1  #goals on
            if g.score2==5:
              self.tree_list[opponent.name][12+g.score1] += 1     #game count
            else:
              self.tree_list[opponent.name][21-g.score2] +=1      #game count
        for k in self.tree_list.keys():
          self.tree_list[k][7] = "%.3f"%(1.0*self.tree_list[k][5]/self.tree_list[k][2])
          self.tree_list[k][8] = "%.3f"%(1.0*self.tree_list[k][6]/self.tree_list[k][2])
          self.tree_list[k] = [str(i) for i in self.tree_list[k]]
      elif int(self.gameType.get())==0:  ########   Doubles
        for g in doubles_games:
          if g.t1p1==player or g.t1p2==player:
            opponent1 = g.t2p1
            opponent2 = g.t2p2
            p1=1
          elif g.t2p1==player or g.t2p2==player:
            opponent1 = g.t1p1
            opponent2 = g.t1p2
            p1=-1
          else:
            continue
          if opponent1.name not in self.tree_list: self.tree_list[opponent1.name] = [opponent1.name,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
          if opponent2.name not in self.tree_list: self.tree_list[opponent2.name] = [opponent2.name,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
          #Opponent 1
          self.tree_list[opponent1.name][1] += p1*g.rating_change  #rating taken
          self.tree_list[opponent1.name][2] += 1           #games
          if p1*g.score1 > p1*g.score2:   #player wins
            self.tree_list[opponent1.name][3] += 1  #wins
            self.tree_list[opponent1.name][9] = max([1,self.tree_list[opponent1.name][9]+1])  #streak
            self.tree_list[opponent1.name][10] = max([self.tree_list[opponent1.name][10],self.tree_list[opponent1.name][9]]) #max win streak
          elif p1*g.score2 > p1*g.score1:   #player loses
            self.tree_list[opponent1.name][4] += 1  #losses
            self.tree_list[opponent1.name][9] = min([-1,self.tree_list[opponent1.name][9]-1])  #streak
            self.tree_list[opponent1.name][11] = max([self.tree_list[opponent1.name][10],-self.tree_list[opponent1.name][9]]) #max lose streak
          else:               #draw
            self.tree_list[opponent1.name][9] =0  #streak
          if p1==1:
            self.tree_list[opponent1.name][5] += g.score1  #goals by
            self.tree_list[opponent1.name][6] += g.score2  #goals on
            if g.score1==5:
              self.tree_list[opponent1.name][12+g.score2] += 1     #game count
            else:
              self.tree_list[opponent1.name][21-g.score1] +=1      #game count
          else:
            self.tree_list[opponent1.name][5] += g.score2  #goals by
            self.tree_list[opponent1.name][6] += g.score1  #goals on
            if g.score2==5:
              self.tree_list[opponent1.name][12+g.score1] += 1     #game count
            else:
              self.tree_list[opponent1.name][21-g.score2] +=1      #game count
          #Opponent 2
          self.tree_list[opponent2.name][1] += p1*g.rating_change  #rating taken
          self.tree_list[opponent2.name][2] += 1           #games
          if p1*g.score1 > p1*g.score2:   #player wins
            self.tree_list[opponent2.name][3] += 1  #wins
            self.tree_list[opponent2.name][9] = max([1,self.tree_list[opponent2.name][9]+1])  #streak
            self.tree_list[opponent2.name][10] = max([self.tree_list[opponent2.name][10],self.tree_list[opponent2.name][9]]) #max win streak
          elif p1*g.score2 > p1*g.score1:   #player loses
            self.tree_list[opponent2.name][4] += 1  #losses
            self.tree_list[opponent2.name][9] = min([-1,self.tree_list[opponent2.name][9]-1])  #streak
            self.tree_list[opponent2.name][11] = max([self.tree_list[opponent2.name][10],-self.tree_list[opponent2.name][9]]) #max lose streak
          else:               #draw
            self.tree_list[opponent2.name][9] =0  #streak
          if p1==1:
            self.tree_list[opponent2.name][5] += g.score1  #goals by
            self.tree_list[opponent2.name][6] += g.score2  #goals on
            if g.score1==5:
              self.tree_list[opponent2.name][12+g.score2] += 1     #game count
            else:
              self.tree_list[opponent2.name][21-g.score1] +=1      #game count
          else:
            self.tree_list[opponent2.name][5] += g.score2  #goals by
            self.tree_list[opponent2.name][6] += g.score1  #goals on
            if g.score2==5:
              self.tree_list[opponent2.name][12+g.score1] += 1     #game count
            else:
              self.tree_list[opponent2.name][21-g.score2] +=1      #game count
        for k in self.tree_list.keys():
          self.tree_list[k][7] = "%.3f"%(1.0*self.tree_list[k][5]/self.tree_list[k][2])
          self.tree_list[k][8] = "%.3f"%(1.0*self.tree_list[k][6]/self.tree_list[k][2])
          self.tree_list[k] = [str(i) for i in self.tree_list[k]]
      #build tree
      try:
        self.vsb.destroy()
      except:
        pass
      try:
        self.hsb.destroy()
      except:
        pass
      try:
        self.tree.destroy()
      except:
        pass
      self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.display_frame,columns=self.tree_headers, show="headings")
      self.vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self.display_frame,orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
      self.hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self.display_frame,orient="horizontal", command=self.tree.xview)
      self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
      self.tree.configure(xscrollcommand=self.hsb.set)
      self.tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,S,E,W))  #, in_=self.display_frame)
      self.vsb.grid(column=1,row=0, sticky=(N,S))  #, in_=self.display_frame)
      self.hsb.grid(column=0,row=1, sticky=(W,E))  #, in_=self.display_frame)
      self.tree.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
      self.tree.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

      for col in self.tree_headers:
        self.tree.heading(col, text=col.title() , command=lambda c=col: sortby(self.tree, c, 0))
        #adjust the column's width to the header string
        self.tree.column(col,width=tkFont.Font().measure(col.title()),anchor=CENTER)
      for k in self.tree_list:
        item = self.tree_list[k]
        self.tree.insert("", "end", values=item)
        #adjust column's width if necessary to fit each value
        for ix, val in enumerate(item):
          col_w = tkFont.Font().measure(val)
          if self.tree.column(self.tree_headers[ix],width=None)<col_w:
            self.tree.column(self.tree_headers[ix], width=col_w)
      sortby(self.tree, "Rating taken", 1)

class Settings:
  def __init__(self,mainmenu):
    self.root = Toplevel(mainmenu.root)
    self.root.title("Settings")
    mainframe = ttk.Frame(self.root,padding="3 3 12 12")
    mainframe.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
    mainframe.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    mainframe.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

    self.title = StringVar()
    self.recentGame = StringVar()
    self.gamesNeeded = StringVar()
    self.maxScore = StringVar()
    self.minMaxScore = StringVar()
    self.allowDraw = StringVar()

    self.title.set(settings['title'])
    self.recentGame.set(settings['recentGame'])
    self.gamesNeeded.set(settings['gamesNeeded'])
    self.maxScore.set(settings['maxScore'])
    self.minMaxScore.set(settings['minMaxScore'])
    self.allowDraw.set(settings['allowDraw'])

    ttk.Label(mainframe,text="Settings").grid(column=1,row=1,sticky=(W))
    ttk.Label(mainframe,text="Values").grid(column=2,row=1,sticky=(W))
    ttk.Label(mainframe,text="Days until player inactive").grid(column=1,row=2,sticky=(W))
    ttk.Label(mainframe,text="Games needed for player to be made active").grid(column=1,row=3,sticky=(W))
    ttk.Label(mainframe,text="Maximum allowed score").grid(column=1,row=4,sticky=(W))
    ttk.Label(mainframe,text="Minimum maximum score").grid(column=1,row=5,sticky=(W))
    ttk.Label(mainframe,text="Allow draws").grid(column=1,row=6,sticky=(W))
    ttk.Label(mainframe,text="Title (restart to take effect)").grid(column=1,row=7,sticky=(W))

    self.recentGame_spin = Spinbox(mainframe, width=5, from_=0, to=1000, textvariable = self.recentGame)
    self.recentGame_spin.grid(column=2,row=2,sticky=(W))
    self.gamesNeeded_spin = Spinbox(mainframe, width=5, from_=0, to=1000, textvariable = self.gamesNeeded)
    self.gamesNeeded_spin.grid(column=2,row=3,sticky=(W))
    self.maxScore_spin = Spinbox(mainframe, width=5, from_=0, to=1000, textvariable = self.maxScore,command=self.newMaxScore)
    self.maxScore_spin.grid(column=2,row=4,sticky=(W))
    self.minMaxScore_spin = Spinbox(mainframe, width=5, from_=0, to=int(self.maxScore.get()), textvariable = self.minMaxScore)
    self.minMaxScore_spin.grid(column=2,row=5,sticky=(W))
    self.allowDraw_check = ttk.Checkbutton(mainframe,variable=self.allowDraw,onvalue=True,offvalue=False)
    self.allowDraw_check.grid(column=2,row=6,sticky=(W))
    self.title_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=12, textvariable = self.title)
    self.title_entry.grid(column=2,row=7,sticky=(W,E))

    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="Save settings", command=self.update).grid(column=1,row=8,sticky=(W,E))
    self.root.bind('<Return>',self.update)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="Close",command=self.quit).grid(column=2,row=8,sticky=(W,E))
    self.root.bind('<Escape>',self.quit)

    for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5,pady=5)
    self.root.focus()

    self.root.mainloop()

  def newMaxScore(self,*args):
    self.minMaxScore_spin['to'] = int(self.maxScore.get())

  def quit(self,*args):
    self.root.destroy()

  def update(self,*args):
    global settings
    settings['title'] = self.title.get()
    settings['recentGame'] = int(self.recentGame.get())
    settings['gamesNeeded'] = int(self.gamesNeeded.get())
    settings['maxScore'] = int(self.maxScore.get())
    settings['minMaxScore'] = int(self.minMaxScore.get())
    settings['allowDraw'] = int(self.allowDraw.get())
    saveGames()
    self.root.destroy()

def sortby(tree, col, descending):
  """sort tree contents when a column header is clicked on"""
  # grab values to sort
  try:
    data = [(int(tree.set(child, col)), child) for child in tree.get_children('')]
  except:
    data = [(tree.set(child,col),child) for child in tree.get_children('')]
  data.sort(reverse=descending)
  for ix, item in enumerate(data):
    tree.move(item[1], '', ix)
  # switch the heading so it will sort in the opposite direction
  tree.heading(col, command=lambda col=col: sortby(tree, col, int(not descending)))

class MainMenu:
  def __init__(self):
    self.root = Tk()
    self.root.title(settings["title"])
    self.root.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    self.root.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
    self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(self.root,padding="3 3 12 12")
    self.mainframe.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
    self.mainframe.columnconfigure(4,weight=1)
    self.mainframe.rowconfigure(2,weight=1)

    self.gameType = StringVar()  #1 = 'singles' or 0 = 'doubles' or 2 = 'pairs'
    self.show = StringVar()    #'ranking' or 'games' or 'graph'
    self.tree_headers = []
    self.tree_list = []


    self.gameType.set(1)
    self.show.set('ranking')

    self.button_frame = ttk.Frame(self.mainframe,padding="3 3 12 12")
    self.button_frame.grid(column=1,row=1,rowspan=2,sticky=(W,N))
    self.gameType_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self.mainframe,text="Game type")  #,padding="3 3 12 12")
    self.gameType_frame.grid(column=2,row=1,sticky=(W,N))
    self.gameType_frame['borderwidth']=2
    self.gameType_frame['relief']='solid'
    self.show_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self.mainframe,text="Game info")   #,padding="3 3 12 12")
    self.show_frame.grid(column=3,row=1,sticky=(W,N))
    self.show_frame['borderwidth']=2
    self.show_frame['relief']='solid'
    self.display_frame = ttk.Frame(self.mainframe,padding="3 3 12 12")
    self.display_frame.grid(column=2,row=2,rowspan = 2, columnspan = 3,sticky=(W,N,E,S))
    self.display_frame['borderwidth']=2
    self.display_frame['relief']='sunken'
    self.display_frame.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    self.display_frame.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

    ttk.Button(self.button_frame,text="Add Singles Game",command=self.addGame).grid(column=1,row=1,sticky=(W,E))
    ttk.Button(self.button_frame,text="Add Doubles Game",command=self.addDoublesGame).grid(column=1,row=2,sticky=(W,E))
    ttk.Button(self.button_frame,text="Add Player",command=self.addPlayer).grid(column=1,row=3,sticky=(W,E))
    ttk.Button(self.button_frame,text="Player stats",command=self.playerStats).grid(column=1,row=4,sticky=(W,E))
    ttk.Button(self.button_frame,text="Settings",command=self.settings).grid(column=1,row=5,sticky=(W,E))
    ttk.Button(self.button_frame,text="Exit",command=self.quit).grid(column=1,row=6,sticky=(W,E))

    self.singles_radio = ttk.Radiobutton(self.gameType_frame,text="Singles",variable=self.gameType,value=1,command=self.update)
    self.singles_radio.grid(column=1,row=1,sticky=(W,N))
    self.doubles_radio = ttk.Radiobutton(self.gameType_frame,text="Doubles",variable=self.gameType,value=0,command=self.update)
    self.doubles_radio.grid(column=2,row=1,sticky=(W,N))
    self.pairs_radio = ttk.Radiobutton(self.gameType_frame,text="Pairs",variable=self.gameType,value=2,command=self.update)
    self.pairs_radio.grid(column=3,row=1,sticky=(W,N))
    self.ranking_radio = ttk.Radiobutton(self.show_frame,text="Ranking",variable=self.show,value="ranking",command=self.update)
    self.ranking_radio.grid(column=1,row=1,sticky=(W,N))
    self.games_radio = ttk.Radiobutton(self.show_frame,text="Recent games",variable=self.show,value="games",command=self.update)
    self.games_radio.grid(column=2,row=1,sticky=(W,N))
    self.graph_radio = ttk.Radiobutton(self.show_frame,text="Spagetti graph",variable=self.show,value="graph",command=self.update)
    self.graph_radio.grid(column=3,row=1,sticky=(W,N))

    self.update()

    for child in self.mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=10,pady=10)
    for child in self.button_frame.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=7,pady=7)
    self.root.focus()

    self.root.mainloop()

  def update(self,*args):
    ################   RANKING    #################
    if self.show.get()=="ranking":
      #Establish active players
      t = datetime.datetime.now()
      for p in players:
        if p.games_played>=settings['gamesNeeded'] and (t-p.last_game).days < settings['recentGame']:
          p.active = True
        else:
          p.active = False
      #Sort players
      players.sort(key=attrgetter('name'))
      players.sort(key=attrgetter('rating'),reverse=True)
      players.sort(key=attrgetter('singles'))
      players.sort(key=attrgetter('active'),reverse=True)
      #Heading
      self.tree_headers=["Rank","Name","Ratings","Games","Wins","Losses","Goals by","Goals on","Av goals by","Av goals on","Max rating","Min rating",
                 "Streak","Max win streak","Max lose streak"]
      self.tree_list = []
      rank = 0
      rankCount = 0
      lastrating = 100000
      for p in players:
        if p.active==False: continue
        if p.singles==int(self.gameType.get()):
          rankCount +=1
          if p.rating != lastrating:
            rank = rankCount
          lastrating = p.rating
          row  = ["%d"%rank]
          row.append(p.name)
          row.append("%d"%p.rating)
          row.append("%d"%(p.games_played))
          row.append("%d"%p.wins)
          row.append("%d"%p.losses)
          row.append("%d"%p.points_for)
          row.append("%d"%p.points_against)
          row.append("%.3f"%(1.0*p.points_for/p.games_played))
          row.append("%.3f"%(1.0*p.points_against/p.games_played))
          row.append("%d"%p.max_rating)
          row.append("%d"%p.min_rating)
          row.append("%d"%p.streak)
          row.append("%d"%p.max_winning_streak)
          row.append("%d"%p.max_losing_streak)
          self.tree_list.append(row)  #may need tuple(row)
      #build tree
      try:
        self.vsb.destroy()
      except:
        pass
      try:
        self.hsb.destroy()
      except:
        pass
      try:
        self.tree.destroy()
      except:
        pass
      try:
        self.toolbar.destroy()
      except:
        pass
      try:
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().destroy()
      except:
        pass
      self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=self.tree_headers, show="headings")
      self.vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
      self.hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="horizontal", command=self.tree.xview)
      self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
      self.tree.configure(xscrollcommand=self.hsb.set)
      self.tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,S,E,W), in_=self.display_frame)
      self.vsb.grid(column=1,row=0, sticky=(N,S), in_=self.display_frame)
      self.hsb.grid(column=0,row=1, sticky=(W,E), in_=self.display_frame)
      self.tree.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
      self.tree.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

      for col in self.tree_headers:
        self.tree.heading(col, text=col.title() , command=lambda c=col: sortby(self.tree, c, 0))
        #adjust the column's width to the header string
        self.tree.column(col,width=tkFont.Font().measure(col.title()),anchor=CENTER)
      for item in self.tree_list:
        self.tree.insert("", "end", values=item)
        #adjust column's width if necessary to fit each value
        for ix, val in enumerate(item):
          col_w = tkFont.Font().measure(val)
          if self.tree.column(self.tree_headers[ix],width=None)<col_w:
            self.tree.column(self.tree_headers[ix], width=col_w)


    #####################   GAMES  #######################
    elif self.show.get()=="games":
      if int(self.gameType.get())==1:
        #Singles
        self.tree_headers = ["Number","Date","Player 1","Score 1","Player 2","Score 2"]
        self.tree_list = []
        num=min([40,len(games)])
        i = len(games)-1
        for i in range(len(games)-1,len(games)-num-1,-1):
          g = games[i]
          row  = ["%d"%(i+1)]
          row.append("%s"%g.date.date())
          if g.score1>=g.score2:
            row.append("%s"%g.player1.name)
            row.append("%d"%g.score1)
          row.append("%s"%g.player2.name)
          row.append("%d"%g.score2)
          if g.score1<g.score2:
            row.append("%s"%g.player1.name)
            row.append("%d"%g.score1)
          self.tree_list.append(row)
          i+=1
      else:
        #Doubles
        self.tree_headers = ["Number","Date","Team 1/Player 1","Team 1/Player 2","Score 1","Team 2/Player 1","Team 2/Player 2","Score 2"]
        self.tree_list = []
        num=min([40,len(doubles_games)])
        i = len(doubles_games)-1
        for i in range(len(doubles_games)-1,len(doubles_games)-num-1,-1):
          g = doubles_games[i]
          row  = ["%d"%(i+1)]
          row.append("%s"%g.date.date())
          if g.score1>=g.score2:
            row.append("%s"%g.t1p1.name)
            row.append("%s"%g.t1p2.name)
            row.append("%d"%g.score1)
          row.append("%s"%g.t2p1.name)
          row.append("%s"%g.t2p2.name)
          row.append("%d"%g.score2)
          if g.score1<g.score2:
            row.append("%s"%g.t1p1.name)
            row.append("%s"%g.t1p2.name)
            row.append("%d"%g.score1)
          self.tree_list.append(row)
          i+=1

      #build tree
      try:
        self.vsb.destroy()
      except:
        pass
      try:
        self.hsb.destroy()
      except:
        pass
      try:
        self.tree.destroy()
      except:
        pass
      try:
        self.toolbar.destroy()
      except:
        pass
      try:
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().destroy()
      except:
        pass
      self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=self.tree_headers, show="headings")
      self.vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
      self.hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="horizontal", command=self.tree.xview)
      self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
      self.tree.configure(xscrollcommand=self.hsb.set)
      self.tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,S,E,W), in_=self.display_frame)
      self.vsb.grid(column=1,row=0, sticky=(N,S), in_=self.display_frame)
      self.hsb.grid(column=0,row=1, sticky=(W,E), in_=self.display_frame)
      self.tree.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
      self.tree.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

      for col in self.tree_headers:
        self.tree.heading(col, text=col.title() , command=lambda c=col: sortby(self.tree, c, 0))
        #adjust the column's width to the header string
        self.tree.column(col,width=tkFont.Font().measure(col.title()),anchor=CENTER)
      for item in self.tree_list:
        self.tree.insert("", "end", values=item, tags=("game",))
        #adjust column's width if necessary to fit each value
        for ix, val in enumerate(item):
          col_w = tkFont.Font().measure(val)
          if self.tree.column(self.tree_headers[ix],width=None)<col_w:
            self.tree.column(self.tree_headers[ix], width=col_w)
      self.tree.bind("<Double-1>",self.editGame)

    ###############   GRAPH   ###################3
    elif self.show.get()=="graph":
      f = makeGraph(int(self.gameType.get()))
      try:
        self.vsb.destroy()
      except:
        pass
      try:
        self.hsb.destroy()
      except:
        pass
      try:
        self.tree.destroy()
      except:
        pass
      try:
        self.toolbar.destroy()
      except:
        pass
      try:
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().destroy()
      except:
        pass

      self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f,master = self.display_frame)
      self.canvas.show()
      self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
      self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg( self.canvas, self.display_frame )
      self.toolbar.update()
      self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)


  def editGame(self,*args):
    if self.show.get()=="games":
      try:
        gameNum = int(self.tree.set(self.tree.focus(),0))-1
      except:
        return
      if int(self.gameType.get())==1:
        EditGame(self,games[gameNum])
      else:
        EditDoublesGame(self,doubles_games[gameNum])

  def addGame(self,*args):
    AddGame(self)
  def addDoublesGame(self,*args):
    AddDoublesGame(self)
  def addPlayer(self,*args):
    AddPlayer(self)
  def playerStats(self,*args):
    PlayerStats(self)
  def settings(self,*args):
    Settings(self)
  def quit(self,*args):
    saveGames()
    self.root.destroy()

def recalculate(singles=1):
  if singles==1:
    for p in players:
      if p.singles==1: p.reset()
    for g in games:
      g.play()
  else:
    for p in players:
      if p.singles==0 or p.singles==2: p.reset()
    for g in doubles_games:
      g.play()
  saveGames()

players,games,doubles_games = [],[],[]
settings=dict()
settings["title"] = "Foosball Tracker"
try:
  loadGames()
except:
  settings['recentGame'] = 31  #days of inactivity which will remove a player from the ranking
  settings['gamesNeeded'] = 20 #games needed to have an ranking
  settings['maxScore'] = 5
  settings['minMaxScore'] = 5
  settings['allowDraw'] = False

if __name__=="__main__": MainMenu()
```

Comment: Does anyone know a good way to make this a stand alone app on Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm tempted to put a bounty on this, but as it stands I'm reading your question as more a 'how can I make this open source & an Ubuntu app', rather than 'How can I improve my code'. Could you update the description to make this more on-topic? You may find [this](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/6429) helpful in doing this.

Comment: Dr Xorile, your latest edit made this question even more 'how can I make this open source & an Ubuntu app', we don't help you with that. We review code by suggesting improvements you can make to it, such as better program structure, performance and memory usage. Again can you change you title and description to match what the site is about, which is outlined in our [help].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not asking for a review.